# Youtube v3 API "id" query parameter length

Tags: youtube-api

I am using the Youtube v3 api (video list function) to retrieve the statistics for some videos uploaded by a client. I filter the list by the video ids.

Does anyone have any idea how long the "id" parameter could be for such request? The reference only states this:

> id - string - The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube video ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a video resource, the id property specifies the video's ID.

Comment: What do you mean by how long? are you trying to have multiple IDs?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I used the word 'long' because it is listed as a string field, so my guess is that the string site itself is the limit.

Answer (score 2):

In theory 50 IDs... you technically can only query 50 videos at a time, so unless you use next page tokens and keep the IDs, you're limited to 50... Personally I wouldn't go above 50 at a time...

Comment: It sounds about right. I'll do some testing to confirm. I think that this is across other list queries.

Comment: This above is correct, the limit for ids in a comma separated list is 50.